# Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I've created a Maven project in Eclipse. I got the below error in pom.xml.

> Failure to transfer commons-lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1 from
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution   will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> Could not transfer artifact commons-  lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1
> from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unsupported or
> unrecognized SSL message

Java version: 1.8.0_291
Maven version: 3.8.6

Comment: UPgrade your JDK version to most recent...

Comment: I had the same error after JDK update. Could you please provide a better solution?

Comment: Are you in a corporate network (firewall, proxy?)

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise

Comment: So you have to configure that correctly or use an optional existing repository manager inside your network which I don't know..